# Embed variables in the Query Module for expressionengine

Tags: embeds, query

Having an issue with the following sql within the query module.

```
SELECT
    exp_channel_titles.entry_id,
    exp_channel_titles.title,
    exp_channel_titles.url_title,
    exp_channel_titles.status,
    exp_channel_titles.channel_id,
    exp_channel_data.field_id_66,
    exp_channel_data.field_id_50
FROM
    exp_channel_titles

INNER JOIN exp_channel_data ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id

WHERE 
    exp_channel_data.field_id_50 = '{embed:member_group}'
OR
    exp_channel_titles.entry_id IN ({embed:additional_projects})
AND
    exp_channel_titles.status = 'open'
AND
    exp_channel_titles.channel_id = '14'
```

This issue I'm having is if the embed:additional_projects variable has no value (or contains no additional project IDs) it throws an error.

The real test for access to an entry comes with the member group I would just like to add additional entries on a per ID basis if need be. Thanks in advance for any insight or help.

Comment: Have you tested putting `{embed:additional_projects}` right before your query to make sure it has the value you're expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a parse order issue. It's the sort of thing you could turn into a custom plugin really easily though, and it would avoid creating any SQL injection security issues at the same time.

Create a new file `third_party/my_plugin/pi.my_plugin.php`

```
<?php class My_plugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE = get_instance();
        $this->EE->db->select('
                exp_channel_titles.entry_id,
                exp_channel_titles.title,
                exp_channel_titles.url_title,
                exp_channel_titles.status,
                exp_channel_titles.channel_id,
                exp_channel_data.field_id_66,
                exp_channel_data.field_id_50')
            ->join('exp_channel_data', 'exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id')
            ->where('exp_channel_data.field_id_50', $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('member_group'))
            ->or_where_in('exp_channel_titles.entry_id', $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('additional_projects'))
            ->where('exp_channel_titles.status', 'open')
            ->where('exp_channel_titles.channel_id', '14');
        $result = $this->EE->db->result_array();

        $this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $result);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
{exp:my_plugin member_group="{embed:member_group}" additional_projects="{embed:additional_projects}"}
    {title}
{/exp:my_plugin}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I was wondering how secure the query module is. Thanks for your insight

Comment: Re security... The query module is fine, the problem comes if you let your users POST a variable (such as `member_group`) which you then use directly in your query without properly escaping it, because malicious users could add whatever they like to your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by passing parse="inward" parameter with query tag:

like:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT....." parse="inward"}

---------------

{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Tried with no success. the embed variable does work just fine currently its when i dont have a variable to place in the sql that it doesnt show. The error is:
    WHERE exp_channel_data.field_id_50 = (1) OR       
    exp_channel_titles.entry_id IN () AND
    exp_channel_titles.status = 'open'

Its the IN () that throws the error